# Problem subtracting datetimes python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following code snippet:

```
    ls3['REP'] = pd.to_datetime(ls3['REP']).dt.to_period('M')
    ls3['month'] = pd.to_datetime(ls3['month']).dt.to_period('M')
    ls3['MonthsBetween'] = ls3['REP']-ls3['month']
```

So rep is a column of values like 2022-05 and month is also in the format YYYY-MM. I want a column that gives me the difference as an integer number of months.

So if my rep column is 2022-05 and my month column is 2022-01, then the difference should be 4. The method above gives me an output `<month-end>` in every row.

I have also tried

```
ls3["MonthsBetween"] = (ls3['REP']-ls3["month"])/np.timedelta64(1, "M")
```

So instead of turning the full dates 2022-05-01 into 2022-05, I subtract say 2022-05-01 - 2022-01-20 and convert this to a month then round it. The rounding causes issues as I don't care how many days are between the two, I really only want to subtract the two month values.

Comment: It's not clear what is the exact issue, overwriting your columns?

Comment: @mozway Sorry seems the use of <> removed the key part! Basically when I run my first code snippet all I'm getting is month-end in every row.

Comment: then check the second part of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you don't have to overwrite your existing columns, perform the computation and assign directly:

```
ls3['MonthsBetween'] =  (pd.to_datetime(ls3['REP']).dt.to_period('M')
                         -pd.to_datetime(ls3['month']).dt.to_period('M')
                        )
```

If you want integers:

```
ls3['MonthsBetween'] =  (pd.to_datetime(ls3['REP']).dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
                        -pd.to_datetime(ls3['month']).dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
                        )
```

Output:

```
          REP    month  MonthsBetween
0  2022-05-01  2022-01              4
```

Used input:

```
ls3 = pd.DataFrame({'REP': ['2022-05-01'], 'month': ['2022-01']})
```

Comment: I get the error 'Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead'

Comment: which line? and which pandas version?

Comment: For the ls3['MonthsBetween'] =  (pd.to_datetime(ls3['REP']).dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
                        -pd.to_datetime(ls3['month']).dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
                        )
Pandas version not sure, should be latest, I'm on a jupyter notebook and just did import pandas as pd

Comment: I provided a reproducible input

Comment: So those are input as strings right? Mine are timestamps. But strftime should fix that.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input for your data, then we'll see ;)